# I can't run inserts in firebird 2.5, Table Unknown

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm trying to create a temporary table to save some codes, but when I try to insert a code it throws me the following error as if the table did not exist:

> can't format message 13:796 -- message file C:\Windows\firebird.msg
> not found. Dynamic SQL Error. SQL error code = -204. Table unknown.
> TEMPCODES. At line 1, column 13.

These are the lines that I try to run:

```
create global temporary table TEMPCODES
(
  codigo varchar(13)
)
on commit delete rows;

insert into TEMPCODES values('20-04422898-0');
```

Why can't it find the table if I'm creating it before?

Comment: I failed to translate

Answer (score 2):

In Firebird, you cannot use a database object in the same transaction that created it. You need to commit before you can use the table.

In other words, you should use:

```sql
create global temporary table TEMPCODES
(
  codigo varchar(13)
)
on commit delete rows;

commit;

insert into TEMPCODES values('20-04422898-0');
```

Also, it is important to realise that global temporary tables (GTT) are intended as permanent objects. The idea is to create a GTT once, and then use it whenever you need it. The content of a GTT is only visible to the current transaction (`on commit delete rows`) or to the current connection (`on commit preserve rows`). Creating a GTT on the fly is not the normal usage pattern for GTTs.